# Apache is not getting started after adding mod_proxy_cluster

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, mod-cluster

i am trying to use my HTTP server as load balancer to my Application-server cluster setup.
so, i downloaded mod_proxy_cluster binaries and added below files to {$apache-home}/modules directory.

```
 mod_proxy.so 
 mod_proxy_ajp.so 
 mod_slotmem.so 
 mod_manager.so 
 mod_proxy_cluster.so 
 mod_advertise.so
```

and also i added below lines in the httpd.conf file.

```
 LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
 LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
 LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
 LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so
```

and then i tried to restart the Apache server but it is not getting started.. i tried a couple of times.. but no luck...
can anybody tell me where i am wrong?
thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu, try to view the apache log file at **/var/log/apache2/error.log**
If there is a line like this :

```
[Wed Aug 13 17:57:19 2014] [emerg] create_mem_node /etc/apache2/logs/manager.node failed: No such file or directory
Configuration Failed
```

So, just create a folder named **logs** in the **/etc/apache2**, then grant the permission to this folder.
No, you can start apache2 by **apachectl start**, then use **netstat -tupln** to check whether apache2 was started. (view port 80)

Comment: Do you know how to configure the path where mod_manager write ?

Answer (score 2):

It is configurable; set `MemManagerFile /your/path/to/httpd/cache/mod_cluster` outside `VirtualHost` scope. Older mod_cluster versions were trying to store shm files in `log/` directory by default. The current versions, 1.3.x, use the proper `cache/` dir though.